# Finding specific Bigram using NLTK Python 3

Tags: python, count, nltk

I have a Problem that should actually be very easy solve with NLTK. I found a solution to my problem, but there they don't use NLTK:

[how can I count the specific bigram words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707617/how-can-i-count-the-specific-bigram-words)

Is it possible to do that with a NLTK function?

Here is my code:

```
food = open("food_low.txt")
lines = food.read().split(',')[:-1]

raw = wordlists.words("cleaned2.txt")
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in raw)

with io.open('nltk1.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as h:
    for m in lines:
        if fdist[m] > 0:
            print(m + ':', fdist[m], end=' ', file = h)
```

I am counting how often the words from the `food_low.txt` appear in the `cleaned2.txt`. My problem is that I have some bigram words in `food_low.txt` and they are not counted. How can I make it that it also counts the bigrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to count unigram and bigram without NLTK and using regular expressions (`re`). Now you do not need two separate calculations, but you can do it in one go with `re.findall()`:

```
import re
import codecs

# List of words and a sentence
l = ['cow', 'dog', 'hot dog', 'pet candy']
s = 'since the opening of the bla and hot dog in the hot dog cow'

# Make your own fdist
fdist = {}
for m in l:
    # Find all occurrences of m in l and store the frequency in fdist[m]
    fdist[m] = len(re.findall(m, s))

# Write the wordcounts for each word to a file (if fdist[m] > 0)
with codecs.open('nltk1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as out:
    for m in l:
        if fdist[m] > 0:
            out.write('{}:\t{}\n'.format( m, fdist[m] ) )
```

Content of nltk1.txt:

```
cow:    1
dog:    2
hot dog:    2
```

Note: If you want to use NLTK, [this answer might fulfill your needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094326/5488275).